# JQuery - How to get all the *html* of elements excluding one

Tags: jquery

This is an example of the HTML:

```
   <div id="block1">
   <div class="header">
   <span category="drink" class="uservar">TEQUILA</span>&nbsp; &nbsp; 
   <span class="block-controls" style="height:15px" contenteditable="false">
   <span title="delete block"><span placeholder="remove block" class="remove">X</span>
   </span>
   </div>
   </div>
```

I want to have a selector that returns everything within the .header div before the "block-controls" child. Sometimes there will be other html elements in the header (as above) before the "block-controls" and sometimes it will be  just text (no span, just the word 'Tequila'. It needs to work in both cases.

This return the text TEQUILA, but not span tag.

```
$('#block1 .header').children().not('.block-controls').html();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will give you the text your specified:

```
    var div = $('<div/>');
    $('#block1 .header').children().not('.block-controls').appendTo( div );
    var x = div.html();
```

[**JS FIDDLE DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/kQJuj/4/)

**OUTPUT**: `<span category="drink" class="uservar">TEQUILA</span>`

**EDIT**

The code has been edited to remove `&& this.nodeType !== 3` as that was addressing nodes that aren't even there!

Demo is updated too.

Further updated per comments below.

Comment: `children` only selects the elements not the `textNodes`, so `this.nodeType` is useless here.

Comment: You are right! I kinda thought I was dealing with `contents`. Will correct. Thanks!

Comment: I want the html if it exists. Not simply the text. So I want the "<span category .... Tequila </span>"

Comment: Ok, guest this, "This return the text TEQUILA, but not span tag." threw me off. Will update.

Comment: Updated. Please check it out now.

Answer (score 1):

What you need is outerHtml:

```
(function( jQuery, undefined ) {
    jQuery.fn.extend({
        outerHtml: function() {
            var html = "";
            this.each(function() {
                html += jQuery( "<div>" ).append(jQuery( this ).clone()).html();
            });
            return html;
        }
    });
})( jQuery );

alert($('#block1 .header').children().not('.block-controls').outerHtml());
```

Check this fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/29eBn/1/

Comment: Not sure what the outerHtml function is all about. I am not removing or appending anything. But the $block1 you wrote returns an error for me: " Error: $(...).not(...).outerHtml is not a function "

Comment: You should add the outerHtml function before calling it as I did above.

Comment: OK. Tried it. It returns all the HTML for the whole header. It does not exclude the  .block-controls

Comment: Updated the function with a better one from: https://gist.github.com/dereli/96bb20a4ad2018af028a

Comment: It can return HTML for multiple items.